# React Recaptcha only on client, is it safe?

Tags: reactjs, client, backend, recaptcha

I am trying to implement google recaptcha to my application's form. 
I am using "react-google-recaptcha" package.

I declared a state of "verification: false", and I set the recaptcha to change this state to "verification: true" when the recpatcha is successful, and the form is only saved to the database in a case that the verification is true.

is this method safe? I have seen that google also offers backend secret keys, and that some developers do the verification process in the back end, but after googling a lot and watching youtube videos, I still cannot seem to understand why do I need to set up recaptcha in the backend if I'm using react.

-Is it safe to do it that way? 
-Can someone bypass it?
-What are the advantages of setting up a secret key in the back end?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with only verifying the captcha on the frontend is that someone could still call the underlying API in an automated fashion. Sending the captcha response in your API request and verifying it in the backend ensures that in order to call the API, they had to successfully fill out the captcha.